# Attempting Multi boot with Truecrypt (Full Disk)

Tags: linux, truecrypt

I am wanting a Windows 7 multi boot with a Linux lvm, currently I have:

```
sda
 sda1 Windows 7
 sda2 Windows page partition
 sda3 extended
 sda5 Linux system 1 /boot 
 sda6 Linux system 2 /boot
 sda7 Linux lvm (with /, swap and /home for both Linux systems)
```

Would I be able to make Truecrypt work for my setup?

I have all the ISOs /backups on disk and USB if a full wipe and start from scratch is needed but I understand that doing this (i.e. Truecrypt) will mean adding a 3rd /boot (as sda3 and moving the extended (to hd0, 4) creating the following:

```
 sda1 win
 sda2 win page
 sda3 /boot (grub)
 sda4 extended
 sda5 /boot (grub stage 2 sys1)
 sda6 /boot (stage 2 sys 2) and
 sda7 holding the lvm
```

Would this be correct?

Comment: i understand the 3rd /boot to be for stage 1 of grub for chainloading from truecrypt BL ---this true?